# how to read a file using fscanf

Tags: c

c
I want to use fscanf to read in a file in the following format.

```
 //text file
 push i
 push o
 pop
 push i
 pop 
 push a
```

a word then a character seperated by a space. Then assign the word to a pointer or var and the same for the char. but I keep getting a segmentation fault error.

```
FILE * fp("text.txt", "r");
char * word = malloc( 21 * sizeof *word );
char data;
int c, size , i, prev;
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %c[^\n]", word, data) != EOF) {
    printf("%s %c", word, data);
}
```

Comment: where are you opening your file

Comment: in code several lines above but I added it to this snipit thanks!

Comment: found my problem since i have "%s %c" for the formating of fscanf if it reads in a pop for word it will read in the first p of the next line for the data char. so some of my words will be missing there first letter any idea how to correctly format this so when i reach a pop which doesnt have a space with a character after it. it wont just assign the first char of the next line to data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer `data` is uninitialized, so when `fscanf` attempts to dereference it, you get the segfault.

What you should do is just declare it as just a `char` (not a `char *`), and change the last `fscanf` parameter to `&data`:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %c[^\n]", word, &data) != EOF) {
                                     ^
```

Also, the `printf` should use `%c` for the second specifier, not `%s` (since you're printing a single character).

Comment: thanks! that worked but now i can see i have another problem where it print out the result it cuts off  the first letter of some words randomly.

Comment: I did that but its still giving me the same problem

Comment: @timmmyjohnson: it's not random, it's after lines with no argument.  So with the line `pop`, it will read `p` (first character of the next line) as `data`, and then for the next line, `word` will be `ush`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're trying to read a word followed by a character, but some lines don't have characters following the word.  `fscanf` is not a good choice for this, because it is not good at differentiating spaces and newlines -- both are just considers "whitespace", so it will read multiple lines trying to match its patterns, ignoring the line breaks.

Instead, read lines with `fgets` and then use `sscanf` to parse each line.

If you really MUST use fscanf, you could use something like:

```
do {
    rv = fscanf(fp, "%s%*[ ]%c", word, &data);
    if (rv == 1) {
        /* read just a word -- no data character after it */
    } else if (rv >= 2) {
        /* read a word and a data character */
    }
} while (rv != EOF);
```

but that gets complicated.